# JVM IntelliJ IDEA permission-level

Tags: java, jvm

The problem is when I try to create a directory by mkdir() it returns false. Looks like the reason is that JVM doesn't have enough permission level. How can I fix it? How to increase this level?

Thank You!

UPD!!! I solved the problem.

Comment: Try running the JVM or IntelliJ as administrator.

Comment: I've solved the problem. It's not about running as admin. But thank you =)

Comment: Can you post the solution? It will help others.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Sure, it's under the question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer. But before I tried smth like that:

```
File fname = new File(currDir + args[i]);//currDir is the path where to create a folder
//and the args[i] is folder name
    if (!fname.exists()) 
        fname.mkdir();
```

But here's a mistake so this is the correct code:

```
File fname = new File(currDir + "/" + args[i]);
    if (!fname.exists())
        fname.mkdir();
```

That's it =)

Comment: Watch out when using `"/"` to separate directories this character can be different depending on your operating system. You should use `java.io.File.separator` or `java.io.File.separatorChar` instead. Or even better for this particular case do `new File(currDir, args[i]);`